# How to Replicate Java console behaviour in Android App

Tags: android, console

I have a Java SE Application that use

`input = new Scanner(System.in);`

to get Input parameters

and use `System.out.println("..");`

to print results

Since all Java APIs used in the original Java Project are also available in Android, I have tried to import all classes without any error, but now I don't know how replicate the behaviour of the classic Java console in Android.

I have seen that there are developers that have achieved this in some IDE-like apps, but I don't know how.

Could you help me?

**Example**: 
assume that you want to port this dummy Java SE Application in Android mantaining the console-like approach of the original code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Please enter your choice");
         System.out.println("A, B");

         Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         String choice = myScanner .nextLine();
         if (choice.charAt(0) == 'A') {
                ...do something
         }
         else{
                ...do something
         }

}
```

Comment: You should be able to see the results from `System.out.println("..");` in the logcat. I've never tried using System.in

Comment: @MatthewWesly I know, but my question is different. I need to replicate the console behaviour... there are developers that have done what I have asked in their apps but I don't know how they have achieved this

Comment: have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673016/building-a-terminal-emulator-for-android

Comment: Are you trying to make something like this http://www.appbrain.com/app/android-terminal-emulator/jackpal.androidterm?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute system commands with `exec()`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792024/how-to-execute-system-commands-linux-bsd-using-java) is how to do it:

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec("uname -a"); // here goes your input
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = "";    
while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

---

Update:

Ok, from what I understand, you would like to compile and run code written by user. I can see 3 options:

1. Most difficult I think. Get the source code of some Java compiler and include it in your project. So, user inputs a text. You compile it, run and give the output.
2. Using already built compiler. This requires root. Install `javac` on your device. Then, in your application you can call it with the above `exec()` code.
3. Easiest one. Using internet and for example, [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/sphere-engine). In your app you send code to compile on Ideone. You get back the output and present it to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I haven't understand how should I use this to achieve my goal(the console should get the input from something like an EditText and print the output (in a TextView or another EditText), to replicate the standard Java console (not the Linux Shell). The original program that I'm trying to port is a Java SE application that use only Java console to do everything. Could you give me more details?

Comment: @AndreaF Ah, I understand better now. See my update.

Comment: I don't want to write a compile and run app like an IDE. I have a Java SE application that use the standard console for input and output and I want to port It in Android without rewrite too much code. All the classes are yet compatible with android, the only problem is that I don't know how replicate the console behaviour easily because I never dealt with this kind of need.