# How to start GPS in Android as a super user?

Tags: android, gps, root

I am creating an Android App that can take GPS position from any other mobile but the problem is that how to start GPS as a super user or linux command to do that.

Comment: Why do you need Superuser Permission ? you  can start GPS as normal user too

Comment: Your question is hard to understand but maybe you need ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in your permission manifest.

Comment: This thread may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543700/android-run-bash-command-in-app

Comment: I already done that using normal GPS on/off but what happens if user doesn't checked his gps on in his/her mobile? then in that case how can we start GPS? i want help on this...